# Monitoring JSON requests sent/received from the browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Having a website that generates and receives JSON requests via AJAX, I failed to find a tool that shows me live the communication including the content of the JSON calls.

I thought that the Google Chrome developer tools or the IE 9 developer tools do have such a feature, but again, I failed.

Searching Google, I failed too.

**So my question is:**

Is there a client-side tool to monitor the content of JSON requests that a website sends to the server?

Comment: Javascript/development questions are a better fit for StackOverflow - see [Does Chrome's Dev Tools have a JSON explorer like Firebug's?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113320/does-chromes-dev-tools-have-a-json-explorer-like-firebugs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use firebug pulgin/addon in chrome and firefox.

1. Open firefox.
2. Search and download firebug addon/plugin.
3. Install it.
4. Open respecitive site whose data transfer you want to monitor.
5. Enable Firebug on that particular site.
6. Check the Net Panel and check the detail of the requests made and more...

Comment: Thank you! From what I learned from @danlefree's link to [this SO posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113320/does-chromes-dev-tools-have-a-json-explorer-like-firebugs) it seems that you can only monitor _responses_. I want to monitor _requests_ initiated by the browser. Is this monitorable, too?

Comment: yeah they are too.. you can monitor each and every request made and their response along with the request headers and response headers too